# sort a column with setCellWidget in QTableWidget

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am trying to sort a column which has progressbar in it. I want column to be sorted by progressbar value. Any help will be much appreciated
[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.tablew = Table(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tablew)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        QProgressBar.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(5.0)
        self.setValue(value)
        self.setFormat('{0:.5f}'.format(value))
        style = ''' QProgressBar{max-height: 15px;text-align: center;}'''
        self.setStyleSheet(style)


class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self,   parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'status'])
        header = self.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.loadData()
        #

    def loadData(self):
        #
        tableData = [[89, 4.8], [99, 3.9], [101, 2.6], [105, 4]]
        #
        self.setRowCount(len(tableData))
        #
        for index, value in enumerate(tableData):
            # column1
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, value[0])
            self.setItem(index, 0, item)
            # column2
            self.setCellWidget(index, 1, ProgressBar(value[1]))
        #


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on answer from @ekhumoro 
Below is the complete code but somehow it doest sort correctly.
Screenshot attached after sorting column manually
[image: probelm in sorting]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.tablew = Table(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tablew)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        QProgressBar.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(5.0)
        self.setValue(value)
        self.setFormat('{0:.5f}'.format(value))
        style = ''' QProgressBar{max-height: 15px;text-align: center;}'''
        self.setStyleSheet(style)


class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self,   parent=None):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'status'])
        header = self.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.loadData()
        #

    def loadData(self):
        #
        tableData = [[89, 4.8], [99, 3.9], [101, 2.6], [105, 4]]
        #
        self.setRowCount(len(tableData))
        #
        for index, value in enumerate(tableData):
            # column1
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, value[0])
            self.setItem(index, 0, item)
            # column2
            item = ProgressWidgetItem()
            self.setItem(index, 1, item)
            item.updateValue(value[1])
            progress = ProgressBar(value[1])
            self.setCellWidget(index, 1, progress)
            progress.valueChanged.connect(item.updateValue)
        self.sortItems(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)


class ProgressWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data(Qt.UserRole) < other.data(Qt.UserRole)

    def updateValue(self, value):
        self.setData(Qt.UserRole, value)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass `QTableWidgetItem` and reimplement `__lt__`, and then add blank items to the progress bar column:

```
            # column2
            item = ProgressWidgetItem()
            self.setItem(index, 1, item)
            item.updateValue(value[1])
            progress = ProgressBar(value[1])
            self.setCellWidget(index, 1, progress)
            progress.valueChanged.connect(item.updateValue)
        self.sortItems(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)


class ProgressWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        # python 3
        # return self.data(Qt.UserRole) < other.data(Qt.UserRole)
        # python 2
        return (self.data(Qt.UserRole).toPyObject() <
                other.data(Qt.UserRole).toPyObject())

    def updateValue(self, value):
        self.setData(Qt.UserRole, value)
```

**PS**:

The implementation of `__lt__` is different for Python 2 vs Python 3, because, by default, the latter will return normal Python types rather than `QVariant` and `QString`. It is possible to directly test whether two `QVariant` objects are equal, but not whether one is less than the other (even if they contain values of the same type).

In Python 2, you can eliminate `QVariant` and `QString` by putting the following code before the first PyQt imports in your application:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
```

This will make the behaviour the same as Python 3, and means you never have to use ugly code like `variant.toPyObject()` or `str(qtstring)`.

Comment: I used your suggestion but when i apply sorting  order i get is 2.6,3.9,4.8,4.0
4.0 is stuck at bottom afetr that no matter how many times I sort table.. 
any Ideas ?

Comment: @django. I checked it again and it works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you made the right changes? Copy my code and replace the last three lines of `loadData`.

Comment: please check above. I have updated my post with new code and screenshit of problem as well

Comment: @django. Please read my previous comment more carefully: copy my code and **replace** the **last three lines** of `loadData`.

Comment: I did replaced  loadData last three lines with your code but It is not working for me. I have Updated my post with complete code as you suggested and attached screenshot of the problem at the end too. Could it be python version problem ? I am using Python 2.7.6.1 and QT 4.8.5

Comment: @django. For some reason, I was certain you were using python3. Anyway, see my updated code and explanation for some solutions.